# SSL session caching in Traefik

Tags: traefik

Does traefik have SSL session caching?

I'm trying to implement the equivalent of nginx's `ssl_session_cache`, `ssl_session_timeout` and `ssl_session_tickets`.

There is a [related issue](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/1161) on the repo, which seems to indicate that there is some sort of support, but there are no docs for this.